# ApplicationException cannot be converted to Throwable

Tags: java, netbeans, weblogic

I'm writing a Java EE Application running on Oracle Web Logic Server and I need to extend the ApplicationLifecycleListener class to create my own listener class to analyze some system variables before starting up the application. If something goes wrong during this initial analysis, I have to block the startup of the application.

Here's my code:

```
import weblogic.application.ApplicationException;
import weblogic.application.ApplicationLifecycleEvent;
import weblogic.application.ApplicationLifecycleListener;

public class WebLogicListener extends ApplicationLifecycleListener {

    @Override
    public void preStart(ApplicationLifecycleEvent ale) throws ApplicationException {

       //...

   }
}
```

the method presStart overrides a superclass method but at this point I have a runtime error when I deploy the EAR file, this error is **"incompatible types: ApplicationException cannot be converted to Throwable"**. The error is notified also by the IDE (NetBeans 8) but it doesn't prevent the compilation of the EAR.

If I go through the library (wls-api.jar) and look at the ApplicationException class, I see it extends weblogic.utils.ErrorCollectionException, which is Throwable on the [Oracle Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLAPI/weblogic/utils/ErrorCollectionException.html). Anyway, if in my code I try to import the class ErrorCollectionException I have this different package:

```
import weblogic.management.utils.ErrorCollectionException;
```

and this works, but I can't use it because I need to raise an ApplicationException to override the method and to stop the application in case of errors.

My enviroment:

- jdk 1.6.0_45
- WebLogic Server version 10.3.6.0
- NetBeans 8

Anyone can help?

Comment: The docs do not mention _throws_ -clause in the ApplicationLifecycleListener#preStart method signature: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13706/lifecycle.htm

Comment: In fact if I override the method without the throws clause it works, but I can't understand why the superclass has this throws clause in the method signature but it works anyway without it. I think that the error "incompatible types: ApplicationException cannot be converted to Throwable" means something different. Anyway I can also use the method without the ApplicationException, but the main question is: how do I notify the application to not start in case of errors without throwing any exception?

Comment: What do you mean by "I have to block the startup". You have a timing issue? There are easier ways around it than what you're proposing to do if that's the case

Comment: I mean that I have to stop the application so that noone can use it in case of errors during the start-up phase. Anyway it seems to be a problem with NetBeans.